# inline edit in a table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I just created one table with 4 buttons `edit`,`delete`,`update`and`Cancel`.All actions are working fine but Cancel only is not working.
Actions:
`edit`-when edit button is clicked input box will ed appended to a rollname column(edit button will be hide and update button will be display)
`update`and `delete`also working fine.
But When I click cancel input  box should be hide in my table.[![enter image description here][2]][2][![enter image description here][1]][1]
Its Not working.
What went wrong?any suggession please

```
var roleList=[{
"Id": "0",
"name":"designer"
}];
$(document).ready(function () {
    empRoles()
});

function empRoles() {

                for (var i = 0; i < roleList.length; i++) {
                    var table = '<tr  id="' + roleList[i].Id + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="roleName" id="name' + i + '">' + roleList[i].name + '</td><td><button  class="btn edit btn-info btn-sm" id="edit' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</button><button  class="btn update btn-success btn-sm" id="update' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>Update</button><button class="btn dlt btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="deleteRow(this)" data-dismiss="modal" id="dlt' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</button><button class="btn editCancel btn-danger btn-sm" id="editCancel' + i + '" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Cancel</button></td><tr>';
                    $('#content').append(table);
                    editUpdate();


}
function editUpdate() {
    //$('.rowInput').hide();
    $('.update').hide();
    $('.editCancel').hide();
}
$(document).on('click', ".edit", function (e) {
    var editId = $(this).attr('id');
    e.stopPropagation();

    $("#" + editId).hide();
    var number = editId.replace("edit", "");
    $("#dlt" + number).hide();
    $("#update" + number).show();
    $("#editCancel" + number).show();

    var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');

    var rowId = $("#" + currentTD +" "+"td.roleName");
    var existingRoleName = rowId.text();
    var updateRoleName = rowId.html('<input type="text" class="inputVal" value="'+ existingRoleName + '" >');

});
$(document).on('click', ".update", function (e) {
    var updatedBy = $("#userName").text();

    var updateId = $(this).attr('id');
     e.stopPropagation();
    $("#" + updateId).hide();
    var number = updateId.replace("update", "");
    $("#editCancel" + number).hide();
    $("#dlt" + number).show();
    $("#edit" + number).show();

    var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
    var a = $("#" + currentTD + " " + "td.roleName");
    var rowVal = $("#" + currentTD +" "+"td.roleName input").val();

    a.text(rowVal);
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    var name = $(this).parents('tr').find(':nth-child(2)').html();
    var Roles = { name: name, role_id: id, updated_by:updatedBy };
    var ajxObj = { oRoles: Roles };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Admin/RoleUpdate",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(ajxObj),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            $(".roleCreated").html("Role Updated successfully!");
            $('.roleCreated').show();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.roleCreated').hide();
            }, 1500);
            // empRoles()
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
});
$(document).on('click', ".editCancel", function () {debugger
    var cancelId = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#" + cancelId).hide();
    var number = cancelId.replace("editCancel", "");
    $("#update" + number).hide();
    $("#edit" + number).show();
    $("#dlt" + number).show();
    var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
    var rowId = $("#" + currentTD + " " + ".inputVal");
    var existingRoleName = rowId.val();
    var updateRoleName = rowId.html('<td>' + existingRoleName + '</td>');

});
```

Full code-     https://jsfiddle.net/xhetgowp/1/

Comment: dude, your fiddle has no buttons.....its very difficult to understand your question

Comment: Not able to understand and review as your fiddle has no output.

Comment: see i have added picture of my data in local

Comment: please check only `editCancel`method based on my image

Comment: Your code looks chaotic and I see `debugger` text in your code, I'm sure there is a syntax error in your code.

Comment: Its working now.Please check

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/xhetgowp/3/

Comment: Updated your fiddle. Check once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this code**

```js
var roleList=[{
"Id": "0",
"name":"designer"
}];
$(document).ready(function () {
    empRoles()
});

function empRoles() {
    
                for (var i = 0; i < roleList.length; i++) {
                    var table = '<tr  id="' + roleList[i].Id + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="roleName" id="name' + i + '">' + roleList[i].name + '</td><td><button  class="btn edit btn-info btn-sm" id="edit' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</button><button  class="btn update btn-success btn-sm" id="update' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>Update</button><button class="btn dlt btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="deleteRow(this)" data-dismiss="modal" id="dlt' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</button><button class="btn editCancel btn-danger btn-sm" id="editCancel' + i + '" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Cancel</button></td><tr>';
                    $('#content').append(table);
                    editUpdate();
              

}
function editUpdate() {
    //$('.rowInput').hide();
    $('.update').hide();
    $('.editCancel').hide();
}
};
$(document).on('click', ".edit", function (e) {
    var editId = $(this).attr('id');
    e.stopPropagation();

    $("#" + editId).hide();
    var number = editId.replace("edit", "");
    $("#dlt" + number).hide();
    $("#update" + number).show();
    $("#editCancel" + number).show();

    var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');

    var rowId = $("#" + currentTD +" "+"td.roleName");
    var existingRoleName = rowId.text();
    var updateRoleName = rowId.html('<input type="text" class="inputVal" value="'+ existingRoleName + '" >');
    debugger;
    rowId.attr("data-existing",existingRoleName);
    
});
$(document).on('click', ".update", function (e) {
    var updatedBy = $("#userName").text();

    var updateId = $(this).attr('id');
     e.stopPropagation();
    $("#" + updateId).hide();
    var number = updateId.replace("update", "");
    $("#editCancel" + number).hide();
    $("#dlt" + number).show();
    $("#edit" + number).show();

    var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
    var a = $("#" + currentTD + " " + "td.roleName");
    var rowVal = $("#" + currentTD +" "+"td.roleName input").val();
    
    a.text(rowVal);
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    var name = $(this).parents('tr').find(':nth-child(2)').html();
    var Roles = { name: name, role_id: id, updated_by:updatedBy };
    var ajxObj = { oRoles: Roles };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Admin/RoleUpdate",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(ajxObj),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            $(".roleCreated").html("Role Updated successfully!");
            $('.roleCreated').show();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.roleCreated').hide();
            }, 1500);
            // empRoles()
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click', ".editCancel", function () {
    var cancelId = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#" + cancelId).hide();
    var number = cancelId.replace("editCancel", "");
    $("#update" + number).hide();
    $("#edit" + number).show();
    $("#dlt" + number).show();
    var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
    var rowId = $("#" + currentTD + " " + ".inputVal");
    var existingRoleName = rowId.val();
    console.log("existingRoleName"+existingRoleName);
    var updateRoleName = rowId.html('<td>' + existingRoleName + '</td>');
    console.log("updateRoleName"+updateRoleName);
    debugger;
     var a = $("#" + currentTD + " " + "td.roleName");
    var rowVal = a.attr('data-existing');
    a.text(rowVal);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="mydata">
                        <thead class="colorBlue">
                            <tr>
                                <th>S.NO</th>
                                <th>ROLE NAME</th>
                                <th>ACTION</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="content"></tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: can you please check your answer..I am just changing that input field value before `cancel action`,when I click cancel button `table td` should not be updated right?but its updating.

Comment: :(:( what you change am unable to understand.

Comment: onEdit I add existingValue to attr().[rowId.attr("data-existing",existingRoleName);] and finally onCancel get existingValue [var rowVal = a.attr('data-existing');
    a.text(rowVal);]

Answer (score 0):

var existingRoleName = rowId.find('input').val();

THis is the solution..